# Writing script for states and capitals

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt

I'm trying to learn Javascript, and I need help with this question that i have been pondering on for a while now.

I need help with writing a script that prompts for the abbreviation of a New England state and alerts the capital of that state. For example if your user inputs NH, your script should alert Concord.

Comment: show the code you have tried.

Comment: var capitals = {ME: "Augusta"' NH: "Concord", VT: "Montpelier", MA: "Boston", CT: "Hartford", RI: "Providence"};

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could do this: if you want to use javascript exclusively, you have two options:

1. Store the associated values in a javascript object

   `var capitals = {AL:"Montgomery",AK:"uhhh..alaska's capital",...};`

   and then your function might look like this:

   `function GetCapitalFor(abbr){
       alert(capitals[abbr]);
   }`
2. Use a third party library

   I don't know of one in particular, but I'm sure one exists.

If you are also working with a server, you could store the pairs in a database and then run the function on the server (probably using AJAX). Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: {abbreviation: abbr}, //where abbr is the user's input (MAKE SURE TO SANITIZE)
    success: function(result)
    { alert(result);}
});
```

and on the server side, you'll query a database table for the abbreviation.

For something as trivial as this though, I'd probably just go with option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Only using the most simple JavaScript:

```
var capitals = { ME: "Augusta", NH: "Concord", VT: "Montpelier", MA: "Boston", CT: "Hartford", RI: "Providence" };
var abb = prompt('Abbreviation?');
alert(capitals[abb]);
```